# User Address relationship MySQL - Database Design

Tags: mysql

I'm getting confused on how I should design my database schema for an Ecommerce site.
I want to create an address profile for my users.

By default, the shipping address is the same with the billing address. 
The user can't create new billing address, but he can add more shipping address.
If there is no shipping address then it will use the billing address as default shippign address..

My problem is that, whenever I change my shipping address or billing address, I must first toggle the "active" field for both of my tables ("billing", and "shipping).

Example

```
Billing Address
1. Miami 

Shipping Address
1. Miami  -(active)
2. New York
3. Boston
```

When I set my Shipping address to new york, I don't like the idea of updating the rest of the fields to 0 and then setting new york to 1.

Is there a better implementation?? Should I just create another field in my users table which indicates the selected address??   Should I merge both Address tables to form one address collection only?

Schema 
  User = id, name

Shipping Address = id, user_id, complete_address, active

Billing Address = id, user_id, complete_address, active

Comment: You're not interested in having some 'third party' code manage all this?

Comment: You could use a single address table and a bit field called `default_address` and that indicates the billing address and the default shipping address

Comment: I don't understand why this is difficult. One table - with bill_street, bill_street2, bill_city, bill_state, bill_zip - all defined as NOT NULL. Ditto for ship_... except they default to NULL until set. So your SELECT logic just checks for ship_... - if it's set to NULL you ship to bill_...

Comment: What if there's a mailing address, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Users
id, name, default_shipping_address_id, ...

BillingAddresses
id, user_id, street, ...

ShippingAddresses
id, user_id, street, ...
```

Is how I would do it. Use the latest billing address for the user. Also make sure you are storing all the meta-data like date-created, date-modified, etc.

Comment: +1 a separate table for billing addresses is useful because even if the user changes their billing address, it's probably a good idea to keep a record of their history of billing addresses, referenced by past orders.

Comment: great answer, although i used it a bit differently (one table for shipping and billing with additional nullable enum column 'type' with options ['billing', 'shipping', null], null means both) couldn't have done it without you, thanks a lot!